# Cypress Automation - AWS quicksight login flow getting failed with session related error

Tags: cypress, amazon-quicksight

Am trying to Automate the Quick sight login flow with Cypress
Please find below the steps and code that is used.
But after entering the password and clicking on submit am getting the below error
Could anyone please help to understand what is going wrong and how to fix it

[Error Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CEkeH.png)

Steps To Automate:

1. Access origin url
2. Enter Account Name and Click on Next
3. Enter User Name and click on Next
4. For Password Authentication it is redirecting to another domain url
5. Then we enter the password and click submit
6. Upon successful login it will be redirected to home page

Below is my code :

```
Cypress.Commands.add(
  "LoginAndNavigateToDashboard1",
  (accountName,userName, password, dashboard1URL) => {
    const args ={password,dashboard1URL}
    cy.session([accountName,userName, password, dashboard1URL],()=>{
      cy.clearAllSessionStorage()
      cy.clearAllLocalStorage()
      cy.clearAllCookies()
      cy.visit("/");
      cy.get("#account-name-input").type(accountName);
      cy.get("#account-name-submit-button").click();
      cy.get("#username-input").type(userName);
      cy.get("#username-submit-button").click();
      cy.origin(
       "https://us-east-1.signin.aws/",{args },({password,dashboard1URL})=>{
          cy.get("#awsui-input-0").type(password);
          cy.get("[type='submit']").click();
          cy.wait(10000)
          console.log(cy.url())
        }
      )
      cy.wait(10000)
      cy.document().its('cookie').should('contain', 'aws-ds-access-token')
    })
})
```